# Rails query: Group by one column and Order by sum of another column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model `PurchaseHistory`. It has a column `user_id` and another column is `amount`. When any user purchased anything it stores the `user_id` and `amount` of purchase.

```
user_id  amount
1        10
2        20
1        20
```

Now I want to make a query that will `group` by `user_id` and `order` by the total sum of `amount` of that user.

So, in this case the query should return something like this

```
[{1 => 30}, {2 => 20}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work
(If it's PostgreSQL DB, use `coalesce(amount, 0)` in case there are any nils, otherwise use your corresponding db methods to cast nil to 0)

```
Hash[
  PurchaseHistory.select("user_id, SUM(coalesce(amount, 0)) as amount_sum").group(:user_id).order("amount_sum DESC").map do |row| 
    [row.user_id, row.amount_sum]
  end
]
```